# Weird behavior on script insertion in html

Tags: javascript, html, iife

I want to insert 2 scripts in the footer html section but I'm having a weird behavior. If I insert manually using  tags in the html itself, it works (index1.html). But if I use an IIFE to create the tags and insert them in same place and same order (index2.html), an error telling 'dummy variable is not defined' is showed in console. Common sense tell me that the error is fine (because dummy is defined after it's used), but why it works for index1.html?

index1.html:

```
    ...
    <script src="script1.js" async></script>
    <script src="script2.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

index2.html:

```
    ...
    <script>
        (function(){
            var loadScript = function(data, callback) {
                var script = document.createElement('script');
                script.src = data.src;
                if (data.opts) {
                    if (data.opts.async) script.async = data.opts.async;
                }
                document.body.appendChild(script);
            }

            var loadScriptRecursive = function(scripts, index) {
                loadScript(scripts[index], function () {
                    if (++index < scripts.length) loadScriptRecursive(scripts, index);
                });
            }

            var scripts = [{src: 'script1.js'}, {src: 'script2.js', opts: {async: false}}];
            loadScriptRecursive(scripts, 0);
        })()
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

script1.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (dummy) ...
    ...
}
```

script2.js:

```
var dummy = true
```

Comment: could it be, because the first script is async?

Comment: I've read that inserting using document.createElement('script') is async by default, that is why i set async=false for the second

Comment: Yes, you are giving yourself a race condition.

Comment: check this: https://javascript.info/script-async-defer
say that "Dynamic scripts behave as “async” by default."

Comment: Yes, my point was that you shouldn't expect the order of the scripts to matter, as you are, when their order cannot be guaranteed.  You need to rewrite your code so this order doesn't matter.

Comment: It seems that after you appended the dynamic script  script1.js to body and it was async, so it loaded before the dynamic script2.js got appended to body. Async means it can load anytime.....Right?

Comment: In the docs https://javascript.info/script-async-defer . Async is given to script which is completely independent of other scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you declare `callback` but have never us it. I assume that you mean something like this `script.onload = callback;`.

```js
(function() {
  var loadScript = function(data, callback) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = data.src;
    script.onload = callback; // NEW LINE
    if (data.opts) {
      if (data.opts.async) script.async = data.opts.async;
    }
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  };

  var loadScriptRecursive = function(scripts, index) {
    loadScript(scripts[index], function() {
      if (++index < scripts.length) {
        loadScriptRecursive(scripts, index);
      }
    });
  };

  var scripts = [
    { src: "script1.js" },
    { src: "script2.js", opts: { async: false } }
  ];
  loadScriptRecursive(scripts, 0);
})();
```

But it's not enough to fix this problem, because of `$(document).ready()`.

Let's look at what the docs say:

> The .ready() method offers a way to run JavaScript code as soon as the page's Document Object Model (DOM) becomes safe to manipulate. [[jQuery]](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)
>
> The DOMContentLoaded event fires when the initial HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images, and subframes to finish loading. [[MDN]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event)

**In the first example, `DOMContentLoaded` fires after JS files were loaded:**

[image: index.html perfomance results]

**In the second example, `DOMContentLoaded` fired immediately without waiting for the JS files:**

[image: index2.html perfomance results]

---

That's why you need to use `$(window).on("load", function() {});` instead of `$(document).ready(function() {});`

Comment: looks fine, worked for me but reading the jquery link you left, for `$(window).on("load", handler)`says: "When this event fires it indicates that all assets on the page have loaded, including images" that is different `DOMContentLoaded` you explained

Comment: The event you described is this right? [load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event) it waits until the rest of files is downloaded

Comment: it works when page content not includes load of other stuffs like images, fonts, etc. But if it's not the case will be a long delay to start that part of code

Comment: Yes, `load` event fires after all content was loaded, where `DOMContentLoaded` fires only when DOM becomes safe to manipulate. If you add scripts using JS, then your DOM is already safe to use, that's why the `DOMContentLoaded` event fires immediately.

Comment: You can change the order of scripts and be sure that all dependencies are ready for `script1.js`, this might help with `DOMContentLoaded` and `loadScript`.